# How to hide an html element with php if a button is pressed?

Tags: php, html, if-statement, isset

I would like to hide a simple div, if someone click a button. The 'details' var holds an id from db.

```
<div class="greetings" <?php if(isset($_GET['details'])) {echo " style='display: none'"; } ?>
  <p> some text </p>
<div>
```

But id doesn't work. I appreciate any suggestions :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative way.

```
<?php
$style = "";
if(isset($_GET['details'])){
    $style = "style='display:none;'";
}?>


<div class="greetings" <?php echo $style;?>>
  <p> some text </p>                       ^ You forgot to close
<div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, its working :)

Oddly, the tag was closed I just screwed here.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the problem is in the sintax of your HTML code. You are missing an ">" to close the open tag.

```
<div class="greetings" <?php if(isset($_GET['details'])) {echo " style='display: none'"; } ?>>
  <p> some text </p>
<div>
```

Comment: The tag was closed I just screwed here :D

Answer (score 1):

Probably it's not a good idea to do it with PHP. PHP runs on your server, which means the browser will have to send a request to your server to process, and wait until it sends a response back to your client to make it work. It's too much for such a simple task.

It would perform much better if you used JavaScript. JavaScript runs on the client's side, which means that when the button is pressed, the action of hiding the div will be processed locally. No need to go all the way to the server so the browser can know how to proceed.

I'm not a JS expert, but if you do it with Angular, you could add a ng-if to the desired div. ng-if adds the html element to the DOM only if a certain condition is evaluated to true. So, in the ng-click method of your button, you just have to set that condition to false and the element should disappear from your html.

Comment: Yes I thought about Js, but im not an expert either. However ill look after it, thank you :)

First I need it to work (if php, its ok for now), after ill change it to other language.

Comment: Nice! Baby steps are the best way to learn. JS is not my favorite language, but Angular made it really cool. Try it when you are done with PHP. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
switch($_GET['details']) {

case 'Yes':
   // do soemthing
   break;
case 'No':
   // do something
   break;
}
```

I hope this work